# AutoMapper: Can't access original object instances passed to Map() from within AfterMap()

Tags: dictionary, automapper

I have code like this:

```
    //Fields
    Product _prod, _existingProd;

    void Test()
    {
        _prod = MakeAndPopulateSomeRandomProduct();
        _existingProd = GetProdFromDb(1);

        Mapper.CreateMap()
        .AfterMap((s, d) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d==_existingProd); //Why does this print false?

            //Customize other properties on destination object
        });

    Mapper.Map(_prod, _existingProd);
}
```

When I call `Test()`, `false` is printed but I expected `true`. In my scenario, it is important to be able to access the original destination `object` via the `AfterMap` argument. I only included the fields to demonstrate the problem but in my real code, I don't have direct access to them. How can I access the object instances passed in to `Map()` when customizing the mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example works. Probably you are using some type converter which creates new instance... Also please provide all mapping configurations to better understand the problem.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AfterMap_Test
{
    //Fields
    private Product _prod, _existingProd;

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, Product>()
            .AfterMap((s, d) =>
                          {
                              Trace.WriteLine(d == _existingProd); //Why does this print false?

                              //Customize other properties on destination object
                          });
        _existingProd = new Product {P1 = "Destination"};
        _prod = new Product {P1 = "Source"};
        Mapper.Map(_prod, _existingProd);
    }
}

internal class Product
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you k0stya, I tried your example and it works for me too. I need to track down the reason my code doesn't seem to be working and will take your suggestions into consideration.